# How to make parent tag and child tag have onclick without repetition on a b-form-checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I have a li tag with some different child tags which also includes a b-form-checkbox. I want the check box to be working when I click anywhere on `li` tag and which also includes on the checkbox.
when I click anywhere in `li` it works fine but when I click on `b-form-checkbox` the `onclick` event is called 2 times and checkbox simply go check and uncheck on 1 click. I have tried many ways like `.self` but then `v-on:click` on `b-form-checkbox` don't work.

`li` tag code below including the `b-form-checkbox` and `template` tag in which they are present.

```
<template v-for="(product, index) in products">
          <div
            class="col-12 col-md-6"
            :key="product.id"
            v-if="!product.responded"
          >
            <li
              class="products-search__list-item"
              v-on:click.self="toggleProduct(index)"
            >
              <div v-on:click.self="toggleProduct(index)" class="products-search__image">
                <img :src="product.img" alt="product.id" />
              </div>
              <div v-on:click.self="toggleProduct(index)" class="products-search__details">
                <span>{{ product.amount }}x {{ product.name }}</span>
                <span v-if="$func.regionCheckGLobal()"
                  >$ {{ product.unitPrice }} / unit</span
                >
                <span v-else>PKR {{ product.unitPrice }} / unit</span>
              </div>
              <div v-on:click.self="toggleProduct(index)" class="products-search__check-box" >
                <b-form-checkbox v-on:click.self="toggleProduct(index)"  v-model="product.checked" > </b-form-checkbox>
              </div>
            </li>
          </div>
        </template>
```

`data()` in script part related variable below

```
 return {   
      products: [],

    };
```

`methods:` code in script part of vue related to `onclick`

```
 toggleProduct(index) {
   this.products[index].checked = !this.products[index].checked;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the  `v-on:click.self="toggleProduct(index)"` from the b-form-checkbox, considering you have so many click handlers that. call the same function, it is unavoidable that they would overlap, just try the click handler on the outermost component, like the <li>, that should prevent call duplication!

Comment: @Komi yes.  I have. as I said without any **onclick** and **.self**. I have tried.  I put only `v-on:click="toggleProduct(index)"` in `li` tag and removed all other click event listeners. it then works fine on all li except when I click directly on `b-form-checkbox` it go chech and uncheck instantly which I think is doing click event 2 times. In other words causing repitition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div v-for="(product, index) in products" :key="index">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6" :key="product.id" v-if="!product.responded">
        <li class="products-search__list-item" @click="toggleProduct(index)">
          <div class="products-search__image">
            <img :src="product.img" alt="product.id" />
          </div>
          <div class="products-search__details">
            <span>{{ product.amount }}x {{ product.name }}</span>
            <span>$ {{ product.unitPrice }} / unit</span>
          </div>
          <div class="products-search__check-box">
            <b-form-checkbox v-model="product.checked" />
          </div>
        </li>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

This is how I modified your template, instead of the input type checkbox you can have the b-form-checkbox, it should behave the same way as the input in my example.
Here is the [Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-dust-n4px9?file=/src/App.vue) link to what I did to make it work, i believe this is what you needed, and now i will explain in more detail:

Since you had all those `click` listeners on all of the child components of the `li`, your click on areas where there was a click listener on for example the `checkbox` and the `div` the `checkbox` was in and the `div` that div with checkbox was in the click event bubbled up to the outermost component, in this case you either put a click listener on the outermost component you want to trigger the action with our every subcompomponent (dont do nested handlers please) that you want the click to be triggered on.

In conclusion DO NOT do nested event listeners!

Hope it helped!

UPDATE: Check your code again for differences between my code and yours, added `bootstrap-vue` for you, and used `b-form-checkbox` in the [codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-dust-n4px9?file=/src/App.vue)! This works as you wanted it to :D

Comment: have u tried it with b-form-checkbox ?  . I mean this one works yup but does it works with b-form-checkbox ?  because I have tried the exact same method before even trying for nest on click or `.self`

Comment: I tried adding b-form-checkbox and it had the same issues. the one I had..  I mean ur method surely works but not for b-form-checkbox thanks for the effort though .. appreciate it.

Comment: @MuhammadUmarKhan Updated my answer please check it out :D

Comment: it is exactly how I did it before `.self` but how is it working for u but not for me. I guess maybe the way I am using the bootstrap plugin in main.js might have caused the issue. I tried and after I did v-on:click.stop.prevent="toggleProduct(index)" it worked for me in my setting but ur method doesn't. maybe because u r importing bootstrap from some `.esm` file and I am using the Bundle method of adding plugins. Anyways ur answer is also correct since it is also working.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer is also correct but not perfectly settling up in my case maybe because of some issues with how I used the bootstrap plugin but anyways.
I used `v-on:click.stop.prevent="toggleProduct(index)"` on the direct parent div where `b-form-checkbox` is present and removed all `click` event listeners except on `li` and `checkbox` and it worked for me.

li on click listener is shown below.

```
<li  class="products-search__list-item"
     v-on:click="toggleProduct(index)
>
```

b-form-checkbox  click listener is shown below

```
<div v-on:click.stop.prevent="toggleProduct(index)"  class="products-search__check-box" >
                <b-form-checkbox   v-model="product.checked" > </b-form-checkbox>
              </div>
```